# Inspiration for scene of exploding whale in "The Many-Colored Land" by Julian May

Tags: saga-of-the-exiles

Back in the late 1980's I was a big fan of Julian May's *Saga of the Exiles* series.

Early on in the first book in the series, titled *The Many-Colored Land*, the character of Aiken Drum leads a team to clean up a beach after a dead whale-like creature washes up on it. He chooses to use explosives and showers the spectators and much of the town with "fist-size lumps of dead whale". At the time of first reading this I assumed it was either a homage to or inspired by the scene with the whale in the *Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*. (I had no reason for assuming this except youthful enthusiasm for all things *Hitchhiker's*).

Recently though I came across this film on YouTube...

It bears a striking similarity to the events described in May's book and I wonder if this was actually the inspiration for the scene. Did she ever talk in interviews about this? Or is it referenced in the companion guide book about *The Saga of the Exiles* (I do not own a copy of it), or in her notes? Quotes from the author would be appreciated if they exist.

Comment: I don't recall it being mentioned in the companion book.

Comment: I'd imagine so. The incident is sufficiently famous that it turns up in all sorts of pop-culture references like Simpsons and Family Guy

Comment: The whale detonation occurred in November 1970. It was all over the news. May moved to Oregon not long after. Inspiration would not be surprising.

Comment: @DoscoJones - The difficulty isn't finding references to the incident, but tying Julian May to it.